# How to install Zend 2.4.8 on wamp in windows 7?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have failed to install Zend 2.4.8 on wamp server in windows 7 32 bit. Can any one suggest me what is the right way to install Zend 2.4.8 for that configeration. ? Thanks !

I have tried more and more. But there is no proper way that i can find to solve this problem. There are many tutorial but no one is working for me.

Also Advanced Thanks !

Comment: It is impossible to answer to this question since you do not say _what_ issue you have. I mean the obvious answer is: download and install. _Why_ doesn't that work for you? What _errors_ do you get? _Why_ isn't the result not usable?

Comment: https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/overview.html This is what you need.

Comment: I have downloaded zend framework, composer, ZendSkeletonApplication-master, But there are many tutorial which is not matching with this dowloaded file that i can't understand what i have to do. Because the files used on the tutorial are not matching with my downloaded files. That is the main problem. Is any exact tutorial about to install Zend 2.4.8 latest version ?

Comment: run composer install. Just read the tutorial. It matches all zend versions.

Comment: Follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwcbLSXcrjM) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

By telling you all steps will make this answer sooo long. So I will provide you best link to refer and complete it successfully.

You can download [Zend Framework](http://%20github.com/zendframework/) on here. and as well as you may need composer too.

> ZF is little hard to install and understand for beginner(freshers) specially who are working first time in any framework specially zend framework 2 installation.There is many website who are providing step to install zend framework in windows machine but personally they haven't put installation step very clearly to keep in mind for freshers.

---

**Tutorials**

[Install Zend Framework in Wamp](http://zurb.com/forrst/posts/Install_Zend_Framework_in_Wamp-GbZ)
[Composer and php environment variable fix](http://blog.makewebsmart.com/composer-and-php-environment-variable-fix/264)

Comment: How to Define composer path in Windows Environment Variable